# Why asp.net menu control is not showing the text?

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net, webforms, menuitem

I am using **asp.net menu control** in vb.net webforms.

It's working but the problem is that the text is not appearing i.e. `text="Standard"`.

It should appear on it.

```
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Standards" Value="Standards">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Templates" Value="1"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Procedures" Value="2"></asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
    <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="Orange" />
    <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="Cyan" />
    <StaticHoverStyle ForeColor="White" />                 
</asp:Menu>
```

Comment: Can you add to your code - there seem to be several closing tags at the bottom, which we can't see the start of.

Answer (score 0):

The text is appearing, but due to below code, as the backcolor and forecolor is white, it seems it is invisible. Kindly try by removing the below code

```
<StaticHoverStyle ForeColor="White" />
```